# disabe an "option" using javascript on a jquery chosen dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have project that is using jQuery and Chosen libraries. I need to mark "disable" some of the elements so the user can still see them but not able to select them.

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Any">[Any]</option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>   
          </select>    
</div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen({});

$(".chosen-select option").each(function()
{   
    let v = $(this).val();    
    if (v.startsWith('Al')) {
        $(this).attr('disable', ''); 
      console.log('disabled', $(this).attr('disable'));
    }    
});

$('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

I've created a demo using jsfiddle but can't see any changes.

Is it possible to disable some options?

https://jsfiddle.net/Bonomi/tns7mq2h/

Comment: just add the attribute disabled to the option tag

Comment: I need to do it dynamically, so need to use javascript

Comment: You can try this way https://jsfiddle.net/Ljzxk0ay/26/